# Using Sorted on a set of a QuerySet

Tags: django-models, django-queryset, wagtail

I have this Page model:

```
class BlogPostPage(Page):
    date_published= models.DateField('Published date', blank=True, null=True)
    intro= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    header_image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image', blank=True, null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+')
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through='blog.BlogPageTag', blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=True)

def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        all_categories = []
        for post in self.get_siblings(inclusive=True):
            all_categories +=post.specific.categories.all()
        all_categories = sorted(set(all_categories))

        context['all_categories']= all_categories
        return context
```

When the page is access I get a TypeError:

> TypeError at /blog/xxx/
>
> '<' not supported between instances of 'BlogCategory' and 'BlogCategory'

Inputs on why this is happening and how it can be avoided are requested.

Comment: I think I found out my mistake. I am trying to sort BlogCategory objects and the sorted method does not know how to do it, on what field. So how do I overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the `key` parameter for `sorted`, according to [key functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

But I am not sure, is `+` allowed in: `all_categories +=post.specific.categories.all()`?